How to use a docker container as environment for a conda project?
I am working on a python project that uses a conda environment. I got access to new resources for testing my project on a server but I can on ly run docker containers there. My supervisor told me to put in the docker container only the environment, but I'm new to docker so I have no idea on how to do it. Until now, I just put the environment and the code into the docker image and run everything from there, with this dockerfile
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# needed to run docker container as non-root
ARG USER=<user>
ARG USER_ID=<userid>
ARG USER_GROUP=<userGroup>
ARG USER_GROUP_ID=<userGroupId>
ARG USER_HOME=/home/${USER}

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GROUP_ID $USER && useradd --uid $USER_ID --gid $USER_GROUP_ID -m $USER

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl


COPY env.yml .
RUN conda env create -f env.yml

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

WORKDIR /app

COPY main.py /app/
COPY src/ /app/src/

ENV PYTHONPATH=/app

USER $USER

ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "python", "/app/main.py", "-C", "src/configs/config.yaml", "--use-splits", "-y"]

In this way, I include the code in the file, but I do not understand how it is possible to use a docker container only as environment.
How should I modify the dockerfile to make it work? And how should I run the script telling it to use the docker container as environment?

A container is an isolated environment.  In normal operation the container can't see the source code on your host system, and your IDE and other host tools can't see the tools and files inside the container.  I've had very good experiences using the Python already installed on my host machine for day-to-day development, only bringing Docker into the picture for final integration testing and deployment.

what about devcontainers, if you use vscode? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers

Unfortunately, there is no vscode in the remote host I have to run the code on. Moreover, I don't have sudo rights to install vscode, so I have to run it from command line with no IDE

You can use VS Code in remote SSH, to modify your remote repo directly. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

If I understand well, you've already built your docker image. If it's not the case, and assuming your are in the folder containing your Dockerfile, simply do:
docker build -t <image name> .

To run your script inside a docker container, the idea is NOT to tell your script that is should run inside it. Conversely, you need to create a docker container and tell it to run you script.

create a container from the image your built (docker run --rm <image name>)
run your script inside this container (conda run -n env python" /app/main.py ...)

However, you specified an entrypoint inside your Dockerfile. This command will automatically be executed whenever your do:
docker run --rm <image name>

However, I think you should use this entrypoint instead:
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "env", "python", "/app/main.py"]

It will allow you to change the options you pass to the script, without having to re-build the image again. You could then run your script in your container with:
docker run --rm <image name> -C src/configs/config.yaml --use-splits -y

In addition, I would suggest to run your container with a volume mapping. This way, you won't have to re-build your project everytime you make modifications in your source code.  Assuming your project is like:
my_project
|__ main.py
|__ src/

Simply go to your project root folder and do:
docker run --rm --volume $(pwd):/app <image name> <your script options>

or whatever options you need to pass.
To sum it up
I would change the entrypoint as stated above, and run your container like:
docker run --rm --volume $(pwd):/app <image name> -C src/configs/config.yaml --use-splits -y


I am not sure if I understood correctly what you said, so correct me if I'm wrong. If I modify the entrypoint, I will be able to specify the arguments when I run the docker container from the command line, so that if I have to run the same script with different parameters I don't have to rebuild anything. On a separate note, if I use volume mapping I can run the code without rebuilding it every time I modify it. Let's say that this project has a git repo, how can I pull the new code without rebuilding the image? And more in general, how does volme mapping work?

You understood correctly I think :) Concerning volume mapping: normally, when you "enter" your docker container, the folder in this new operating system have nothing in common with your local operating system. Volume mapping serves to share a local folder with another folder inside the containing. It is a bit like synchronysing a folder on your computer with a folder on your cloud. Therefore, if you perform a git pull on your repo, and if your volume mapping is correct, you'll see the updates inside the container

Docker is cumbersome to understand for beginners, but since it's used everywhere right now, it deserves to be understood. To dive a little bit into what are images and containers, I suggest you run your container in interactive mode. Do docker run --rm -it --volume $(pwd):/app --entrypoint /bin/bash . It's going to open a shell session inside your new container, where you can navigate and launch your scripts like in your local shell

So, I tried your solution and it apparently works on the machine I was testing it on, but not on the host machine that I should use. I used the volume flag for both the source code and the data that I had to read. In both these cases I had a folder called data/Dataset/. I used volume mapping to map this folder into /app/data/Dataset/. In the machine I tested this on, it worked, it created the folder /app/data/Dataset/ and mapped all data inside it, while on the host machine it created the folder but did not map the data. What did I get wrong?

For completeness, the command I used is
docker run -v /home/<user>/data/Dataset/:/app/data/Dataset -v $(pwd):/app/ --rm <image_name> <script-arguments>

The way you mapped volumes will create a conflict because in both cases you target the /app folder in the container. I think it might be the reason of the issue

Thank you for the insight, that was exactly the problem. I created two subfolders and mapped the two volumes in those subfolders
